# How to hide selected list item from list in angular2 template?

Tags: angular, ng-hide

I am trying to hide list item which is selected and added to another list but don't know what to apply so added item does not show in list.

```
  <div class="countries-list">
    <span class="countries-list__header">{{'GeneralOrganizationalBackgroundSurveyComponent-STEP_6_ALL_LOCATIONS' | translate}}</span>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let country of filteredCountries"
            (click)="selectCountry(country, 'add')"
            class="add"
            [ngClass]="{'selectedCountry':   selectedCountry?.name == country.name && selectedCountry?.action === 'add',
                        'disabledSelection': selectedCountry?.disabledSelection && selectedCountry?.name == country.name}">
            {{ country.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="contries-controllers">
    <a class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light cyan darken-3"
       [ngClass]="{'disabled': selectedCountry === null || selectedCountry?.action === 'delete'}"
       (click)="addCountryFromForm(selectedCountry.code)">
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code into your question

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an exact use case for the [*ngIf](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif) directive, e.g.:

`<li *ngIf='!selectedCountries.includes(country.code)'`.